# Split list into list of horizontally grouped sub lists

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have the following list of items:

```
List: [Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5, Item 6, Item 7, Item 8, Item 9]
```

I need the following output:

```
List 1: [Item 1, Item 4, Item 7]
List 2: [Item 2, Item 5, Item 8]
List 3: [Item 3, Item 6, Item 9]
```

After some research I "came up" with the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int parts)
    {
        var list = new List<T>(source);
        int defaultSize = (int)((double)list.Count / (double)parts);
        int offset = list.Count % parts;
        int position = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < parts; i++)
        {
            int size = defaultSize;
            if (i < offset)
                size++;

            yield return list.GetRange(position, size);

            position += size;
        }
    }
```

This works but distributes the items vertically and I need the spread out horizontally.

Thought? Thanks!

===== UPDATE ====

In case the count in source is not evenly divided by parts, this result must be like so:

```
List 1: [Item 1, Item 5, Item 9]
List 2: [Item 2, Item 6, Item 10]
List 3: [Item 3, Item 7]
List 4: [Item 4, Item 8]
```

Comment: What should happen when the count in source is not evenly divided by parts?  Which list should have the extra piece?  Or should that item just be truncated off the resulting lists?

Comment: Good question. See update :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int parts) 
{
    var list = new List<T>(source);    
    foreach (var group in list.GroupBy(x => list.IndexOf(x) % parts)) 
    {
        yield return group.ToList();
    }
}
```

work?